# get object ID after insert in database in asp.net MVC with oracle databse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework-5

please, i need help to retrieve ID(primary key) of the object i have inserted in oracle database, many suggestion said:

```
 context.Entity.add(myObject);
 context.SaveChanges();
 int x=myObject.ID;
```

but that didn't work.
when i tries to print x in the following statement in controller:

```
return View(x.ToString());
```

(Since i can't print this value in another way), i receive the value "0", but when i open the database i found a value for ID (not "0")
my oracle database has sequence and trigger to assign ID to myObject.
i don't know where the problem is, in database? or compatibility problem between database and MVC? 
Thank you in advanced:)

Comment: you should probably add EntityFramework as a tag on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on your model. EF needs to know that the field in question is set in the db.

In your model, add the DatabaseGenerated option like this:

```
public class myObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The [options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx) that can be used with DatabaseGeneratedOption are **Computed** (generated on insert and update), **Identity** (generated on insert), and **None** (not generated).

Once you do this, EF knows to get the value back from the DB after a save. Otherwise, it assumes the db isn't touching the values you send.

Comment: Thank you very much :) @Frank Luke